# GetDate with minus 30 minutes and display in UTC

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to display the current date with -30 minutes. And get the output in UTC format.

Below are the things I tried.

```
Clear-Host
$dte = Get-Date
$Minusthirty= $dte.AddMinutes(-30)
Write-Output "This is CurrentDate: " $dte
Write-Output "This is Minus30: " $Minusthirty
```

OUTPUT
Wednesday, April 1, 2020 2:38:43 AM

I want to display the output as "2020-04-01T00:30"

Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're showing isn't UTC format - your desired output format has a time-of-day component, but no UTC offset (`-00:00`) or UTC indicator (`Z`).

To format the local point in time minus 30 minutes in the format shown in the question:

```
[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-30).Tostring('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm')
```

To express the current UTC point in time minus 30 minutes in the same format:

```
[datetime]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30).Tostring('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm')
```

Note:

- `[datetime]::Now` is the same as `(Get-Date)`.
- As of PowerShell 7.0, there is no direct equivalent to `[datetime]::UtcNow` (short of the cumbersome `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()`) but an `-AsUtc` switch to `Get-Date` is coming, presumably in 7.1; see [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11611).